# Algorithm: Best way to create solve this algorithm scenario

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a problem and I wanted to create an algorithm to solve it. But I am wondering if my computation is right or I should improve it. This is the algo problem:

> Create an algorithm that will compute for the grade of a student. The grade is equal to one-third of the minor exam and two thirds of the major exam. Print the student grade.

The algorithm I created is:

1. Read the grades.
2. Compute the midterm and minor grade using the following formula:
   `grade = 1/3 * minor exam + 2/3 * major exam`.
3. print the grade

I don't know if my formula is correct.

Comment: If your algorithm is implemented in one specific language, tag it as such. But don't spam all programming languages you can. I re-tagged this as "language-agnostic". Feel free to edit it if you want an answer on a specific language (there might have some shortcuts), showing what you've tried. Also if you don't know if your formula is correct, you can easily verify it with some inputs.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried and specifics about the problem(s) that you are having with it.

Comment: @Ali Beadle no codes is needed there. I just need what is the algorithm of it step by step just like what I put in the above.

Comment: How is the input given? One student at a time?

Comment: Hi @amit, Yeah I should also include input in algo above. But can you help me on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know if my formula is correct.

Mathematically speaking - this is indeed the formula for the problem you describe. However, note that in many languages, `1/3 * minor exam + 2/3 * midterm exam`  will be parsed as integer arithmetic operations, and that will lead to wrong answer (always 0).

The reason is, in integer arithmetic, when calculating `a/b`, the returned answer is `floor(a/b)` (where `floor(.)` is the closest not higher integer).

To make sure this does not happen - make sure to convert your number to floating points, and use floating points arithmetics - while they have their inaccuracy issues as well, this is seldom a problem when dealing with such a small formula and with relatively low numbers (in absolute value).

Comment: Thank you very much. Ahm really my formula is correct?